# Solidity variable definition: (bool sent, )

Tags: solidity

In Solidity, this sentence:

> (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: _amount}("");

What is the sense of that "," after sent variable?

Any link to offcial documentation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It means you do not need to define both the variables to access the return values. You can access either of these variables as follows

```
    (,uint256 alpha) = testFunction(); //access first returned variable
    (uint256 beta,) = testFunction(); //access second returned variable
            function testFunction() public pure returns(uint256,uint256){
                    return (1,2);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solidity functions can return multiple variables of different types.

If you only want to keep one variable, then you can declare a variable and then use commas:

```
function multiValueFunction() public returns (bool, string memory, uint[] memory, uint {
//do something
return (true, "New String", [1,2], 21)
}

function differentFunction() public {
uint numberToKeep;
(,,,numberToKeep) = multiValueFunction();
}
```

Expected: numberToKeep = 21

Each comma represents the place of a returned variable (that is not kept)

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the function will return two variables and you just want to store the first one.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of syntax (variable type) is called ***Tuple*** In Python and other languages.

In Solidity,

- they're not considered a proper type but can be used as a **shorthand**.
- See the **Official Docs**: [Destructuring Assignments and Returning Multiple Values](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/control-structures.html?highlight=tuples#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values)

example:

```
uint256 amount = 10 ether;
require(
  amount <= address(this).balance,
  "Trying to withdraw more money than the contract has."
);
(bool success, ) = (msg.sender).call{value: amount}("");
require(success, "Failed to withdraw money from contract.");
```

above code, Roughly, Can be translated with basic `if` `else` statements like following:

```
uint256 amount = 10 ether;
bool success;

if(amount <= address(this).balance) {
  success = true;
} else {
  success = false;
  return "Trying to withdraw more money than the contract has.";
}
if(success) {
  (msg.sender).call{value: amount}("")
} else {
  return "Failed to withdraw money from contract.";
}
```

here's [another contract as example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85224/access-tuples-elements),

use this link https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.6.9+commit.3e3065ac.js&optimize=false&gist=83bfbd85ef79387f760154999eb4f192&runs=200&evmVersion=null to play around in `remix` online

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.8.0;

contract myContract {
    uint index;

    function myFunction() public {
        ( , , uint256 standardDepositAmount, , ) = returnTuple();
        require(standardDepositAmount == 3);
        // do something...
    }
    
    function returnTuple() public pure returns (uint, uint, uint, uint, uint) {
        return (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- Solidity internally allows tuple types, i.e. a list of objects of potentially different types whose number is a constant at compile-time.  
2 - Tuples are not proper types in Solidity, they can only be used to form syntactic groupings of expressions.

from official docs https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/control-structures.html?highlight=tuples#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values 

@KarlKnechtel pls solidity is releasing new version a lot, so considering that this is old thread and below answers are valid, is Wrong.

Comment: whatever man :) @KarlKnechtel